# I'm having two Windows 7 installed and running in my laptop. How can I delete the other one? 

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have another concern with my laptop.

When I had a problem with the microphone, I tried to restore the system. But sadly, I had a mistake with the process and accidentally it was formatted. Its a built in laptop. (Toshiba m840, Windows 7, 64 bit)

After the format process, programs were automatically installed. Until a friend of mine told me that I might have 2 Windows installed already. When we checked the program, he was right.

I'm having 2 program files folders, which means I really have 2 Windows installed and running in my laptop. Supposed to be, there should be only 1 right?

Can anyone help me how to delete the other Windows? Because I think it is occupying much space in the hard drive. They say it could make my laptop become slower.

Answer (score 2):

> Its a built in laptop. (Toshiba m840, Windows 7, 64 bit)
>
> I'm having 2 program files folders, which means I really have 2 Windows installed and running in my laptop. Supposed to be, there should be only 1 right?

You're running a 64-bit version of Windows, which *will* have 2 versions of Program Files

- Program Files
- Program Files (x86)

The latter is where 32-bit programs generally get installed at, so having 2 such folders doesn't really mean you have 2 instances of Windows installation.

If you did have 2 instances of Windows installed, then you'll be prompted to select one when you start your laptop/

> Because I think it is occupying much space in the hard drive. They say it could make my laptop become slower.

That's not really true

Comment: so you mean, it's impossible to have 2 windows running at the same time? yea, i saw that (program files and program filesx86. and upon seeing that folders, we thought 2 windows were installed. and i dont really have to worry, right? thank you soo much! what a relief! :))

Comment: @mandy It is possible, but in your case, you've got nothing to worry.

Comment: oh, thank you very much.. my mind is at peace now. :D have a great time! :))